# Janrain engage doesnt work with facebook login

Tags: facebook, magento, janrain

I installed the janrain engage plugin in my magento site,configured it and its working fine with live,yahoo and google but when it comes to fb it gives me an error. the first time someone logs in it works perfect but when they logout and try to relogin with the same facebook account they get redirected to mysite/janrain-engage/rpx/duplicate/  and that shows an error message (There is already an account with this email address. If you are sure that it is your email address, click here to get your password and access your account.) If they use their email and the password they get by email they can login so i think i have configured smth wrong in my fb app. Anyone can give me a full guide on how to configure the fb-app properly or if there's smth I have to change in the janrain admin panel?

Comment: Are you sure that you have configured your facebook app properly?

Comment: quoting myself "Anyone can give me a full guide on how to configure the fb-app properly or if there's smth I have to change in the janrain admin panel?" so I'm not sure P.S "Sorry about the late answer im new at this"

Comment: I hope you will be provided a step-wise configuration wizard for your facebook app at janrain. Just follow those steps properly.